# Primefaces schedule: how can I select a range of days?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, fullcalendar, schedule

I'm using primefaces schedule component. I would like to select a range of days to create a n-days event just pressing the mouse button on the starting date and releasing it on the end date. Full calandar allows that:

http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.2/demos/selectable.html

How can I do the same with the primefaces component? I guessed it was based on jquery fullCalendar, but it seems to me you can click only on a single date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, Primefaces doesn't support the creation of a n-days event by simply dragging the mouse, but you still could implement the fullCalendar widget instead of Primefaces schedule.
All you have to do is to use the jquery provided by Primefaces:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
```

or

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
```

Otherwise you could create conflicts.